# syn match in vimrc but highlight not ok

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I have a vimrc file

```
" activates filetype detection
filetype plugin indent on

" activates syntax highlighting among other things
syntax on
set autoindent
colorscheme default
highlight Comment ctermfg=DarkGreen
    
syntax match dollar "/\$\w*"
highlight dollar ctermfg=magenta
```

And i want all words with a `$` in magenta... But when I open a file, all words with `$` are in yellow...
And when i try to test the regex with just `:/\$\w*`, all `$word` are selected... So I don't understand why highlighting is not OK...

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
:syntax match {group-name} {pattern}
```

`<pattern>` is a *pattern*, not a search command, so you should drop the `/` from:

```
syntax match dollar "/\$\w*"
```

in order to get:

```
syntax match dollar "\$\w*"
```

which works as expected:

[image]